# RTD Excel function return "#N/A". How to run Lightstreamer Excel (RTD) Client?

Tags: c#, excel, windows, rtd

I have problem with Lightstreamer-Basic Stock-List Demo - Excel(RTD)Client (https://github.com/Lightstreamer/Lightstreamer-example-StockList-client-rtd). I have installed Lightstreamer Server locally which work perfectly(http://localhost:8080). I want to updating my spreadsheets in real-time so I installed Lightstreamer - Basic Stock-List Demo - Excel(RTD)Client.
I done every steps from section "Install", but when open ExcelDemo.xlsx every cells show "#N/A".
In A1 cell entered "=RTD("lightstreamer.rtdexceldemo",,"CONFIG","http://localhost","8080","DEMO","QUOTE_ADAPTER")"
Do you have idea how to repair this bug ?

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.lightstreamer.com/showthread.php?878-RTD-Demo-will-not-connect-to-Lightstreamer-Server

The above message may help.

The step is:
- add RTDServiceRegistrationExample.reg with Lightstreamer-example-StockList-client-rtd-master.zip
- Modify the correct location of RTDLibraryExcelDemo.dll by regedit
- Restart computer
- Run ExcelDemo.xlsx, Lightstreamer server will work together.

Enjoy!

Ricky